# What is the simplest way of applying different head to different level?

Tags: list-manipulation

Below is the code for applying same head f to all the levels that are indicated

```
Apply[f, {{{{{a}}}}}, {0, 3}]
```

Now if we want to apply f to level 0, g to level 1, h to level 2, ..., what would be the simplest form?

Answer (score 5):

**Using `FoldList`:**

```
lis = {{{{{a}}}}};
fAt = {{f, 0}, {g, 1}, {h, 2}, {j, 3}};
(res = FoldList[Apply[First@#2, #1, {Last@#2}] &, lis, 
    fAt]) // TableForm
```

To see the final result only, use `Fold` instead of `FoldList`.

---

[image]

---

*Visualization:*

```
TreeForm /@ {lis, res}
```

[image]

---

**Addendum**

If you are not comfortable (yet) with using `FoldList`, then use the following and modify the steps as you see fit:

```
res2 = lis // Apply[f, #, {0}] & // Apply[g, #, {1}] & // 
   Apply[h, #, {2}] & // Apply[j, #, {3}] &

Last@res == res2

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `MapIndexed`:

```
MapIndexed[{f, g, h, j}[[Length[#2] + 1]] @@ # &, {{{{{a}}}}, {{a}}}, {0, 3}]
```

> f[g[h[j[{a}]]], g[h[a]]]

Answer (score 2):

Using `Fold` and `Map`

```
 Fold[Map[#2[[1]], #1, #2[[2]]] &, {{{{{a}}}}}, {{f, {0}}, {g, {-1}}}]
```

f[{{{{{g[a]}}}}}]